# Vowpal Wabbit combinations

Tags: vowpalwabbit

Here's an example of some data

```
date,trophies,characters
2017-07-26,4119,goblin_gang13 bowler5 ice_wizard2 order_volley12 mirror6 goblin_barrel6 the_log2 inferno_dragon3
2017-07-26,4149,fire_fireball9 minion12 archers12 angry_barbarian12 tombstone8 chr_golem7 mega_minion9 zap12
```

Feature selection works great! But it gives me the best single character. Is there some way to get the best 8 character combination?

I'm trying --interactions abcdefgh, but I don't think I'm doing it right because the features are still a single character. Thanks :)

Edit: For the sake of brevity, I'll just include the data from the train generated file and the amazing github project by Ariel F that works with csv files

https://github.com/arielf/weight-loss

`3062.00 | fire_fireball8 giant7 building_inferno7 musketeer7 fire_spirits10 mega_minion7 skeletons8 zap11
-1812.00 | goblins10 baby_dragon5 building_elixir_collector8 dark_witch1 lightning6 chr_golem5 mega_minion9 the_log1 goblins10 baby_dragon5 building_elixir_collector8 dark_witch1 lightning6 chr_golem5 mega_minion9 the_log1 goblins10 baby_dragon5 building_elixir_collector8 dark_witch1 lightning6 chr_golem5 mega_minion9 the_log1
-1803.00 | giant10 valkyrie9 minion_horde12 rage_barbarian3 chr_witch7 lightning6 bomber12 zap12 giant10 valkyrie9 minion_horde12 rage_barbarian3 chr_witch7 lightning6 bomber12 zap12 giant10 valkyrie9 minion_horde12 rage_barbarian3 chr_witch7 lightning6 bomber12 zap12
-1803.00 | giant10 valkyrie9 minion_horde12 rage_barbarian3 chr_witch7 lightning6 bomber12 zap12 giant10 valkyrie9 minion_horde12 rage_barbarian3 chr_witch7 lightning6 bomber12 zap12 giant10 valkyrie9 minion_horde12 rage_barbarian3 chr_witch7 lightning6 bomber12 zap12
-1668.00 | fire_fireball7 baby_dragon4 musketeer7 miner1 bandit1 fire_spirits9 mega_minion7 mini_pekka7 fire_fireball7 baby_dragon4 musketeer7 miner1 bandit1 fire_spirits9 mega_minion7 mini_pekka7 fire_fireball7 baby_dragon4 musketeer7 miner1 bandit1 fire_spirits9 mega_minion7 mini_pekka7`

Comment: Your data isn't in VW format. Are you sure you use it with VW and it works? What is your VW commandline?
The `--interactions` works with `naespaces` of features. That means you shall assign your feature to namespace like ` |a f1 f2 |b f3 |c f4 f5 f6` beforehand. Then you can interact required namespaces with `--interactions abc`. Check wiki: https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Input-format

Comment: @truf thank you so much! If order doesn't matter, and I want to see the interactions of all 8 characters, do I just do |a f1 |b f2? Again, order doesn't matter so sometimes it might say |a f2 |b f1

Comment: yes. I think you can also do `|a f1 f2 f3 fn` with `--interactions aaaaaaa`. Or even just `--interactions ::::::::` where : is a special character that match any namespace (and features without namespace are assigned to namespace with character 0x20 (space character)). So you can just `--interactions ::::::::`. Rules of feature interaction with itself described here https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Command-line-arguments

Comment: or better `--interactions \\x20\\x20\\x20\\x20\\x20\\x20\\x20`

Comment: Thank you so much! @truf it's running right now on 100 lines of data and taking a few minutes. To run 8 combinations on 37k lines of data might be too computationally expensive. Is there a way to use a neural net (-nn) instead of the interactions flag? Or is --interactions on 37k lines of data feasible?

Comment: `--interactions` is rather data pre-processing step. It generates new features "on fly" at runtime. You can try it with `-nn` or other models, but it won't make VW work faster as default SGD algorithm is fastest it has.

Comment: Also performance with such high order of interactions depends much more on number of features in each raw rather than number of raws. E.g. if your number of raws increased twice your calculation will take twice longer. But if your number of features increase (number of raws the same) - it may take thousand time longer. So if your number of features is fixed to 24 you may estimate time it will take for any number of raws.

Answer (score 1):

you can just `--interactions ::::::::` where `:` is treated in VW as a special character that match any namespace (and features without explicitly defined namespace are assigned to namespace with character code 0x20 (space character)). Rules of namespace interaction with itself are described here https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Command-line-arguments
**UPD:** `--interactions \\x20\\x20\\x20\\x20\\x20\\x20\\x20` (with \x20 we refer to default namespace directly) should perform faster. `\\` is `\` with escape character for bash command line.